# pushed encoded json into another json

Tags: php, json

I'd encoded my result into json and I want to merge them. I wish to achieve this

```
[
    {
        "post_id": 1,
        "content": "test image feature",
        "date": "0000-00-00",
        "category_id": 1,
        "lp_title": "",
        "lp_image": "",
        "lp_canonicalUrl": "",
        "lp_url": "",
        "lp_desc": "",
        "lp_iframe": "",
        "lp_iframe_id": ""
        "img_src" [{img_src:1.jpg},{img_src:2.jpg}]
    }
]
```

http://pastebin.com/7jKp9BUn

the result of each statement

```
[
    {
        "img_src": "1.jpg"
    },
    {
        "img_src": "2.jpg"
    }
]
```

the next one

```
[
    {
        "post_id": 1,
        "content": "test image feature",
        "date": "0000-00-00",
        "category_id": 1,
        "lp_title": "",
        "lp_image": "",
        "lp_canonicalUrl": "",
        "lp_url": "",
        "lp_desc": "",
        "lp_iframe": "",
        "lp_iframe_id": ""
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can decode the JSON into arrays, append one to the other, then re-encode:

```
$s1 = '[
    {
        "img_src": "1.jpg"
    },
    {
        "img_src": "2.jpg"
    }
]';
$s2 = '[
    {
        "post_id": 1,
        "content": "test image feature",
        "date": "0000-00-00",
        "category_id": 1,
        "lp_title": "",
        "lp_image": "",
        "lp_canonicalUrl": "",
        "lp_url": "",
        "lp_desc": "",
        "lp_iframe": "",
        "lp_iframe_id": ""
    }
]';

//decode each
$arr1 = json_decode($s1, true);
$arr2 = json_decode($s2, true);
$arr2[0]['img_src'] = $arr1;
//re-encode as a JSON string and show output
$sf = json_encode($arr2);
echo $sf;
```

This should give the result you described, with "img_src"... as a sub-array of the larger set.

Comment: @AlanYong - it looks like you made `$arr2` a child of `$arr1` instead of the other way around. `$arr1` has your small img_src set. `$arr2` has the rest. You need to add `$arr1` as a child of `$arr2` in the case I described.

Comment: That will give you **objects**. Second param of `json_decode` should be `true` to return an array.

Comment: @AlanYong - see the edited code. You need to pass that second argument for the decode to return an array instead of an object, then add `$arr1` to `$arr2[0]['img_src']`

Comment: @scrowler - just edited that right before your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your php code you could do it this way as well in one shot.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("
SELECT  post_id,content,date,category_id,lp_title,lp_image,lp_canonicalUrl,lp_url,lp_desc,lp_iframe,lp_iframe_id
    FROM post_items inner JOIN user ON post_items.user_id = user.user_id
    WHERE post_items.user_id = ? order by post_items.post_id desc LIMIT ?,?");

$stmt->bind_param('iii', $userid, $itemStart, $itemEnd);

$stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT photo_upload.img_src FROM photo_upload inner JOIN post_items ON post_items.photo_set_id = photo_upload.photo_set_id 
     WHERE post_items.photo_set_id = photo_upload.photo_set_id ");

//store the images in a separate array
$imgArray = array();
if ($stmt2->execute()) {
    $photo_items = $stmt2->get_result();

    while ($obj2 = $photo_items->fetch_object()) {
        $imgArray[] = $obj2;
    }       
}

if($stmt->execute()){

    $post_items = $stmt->get_result();

    if(mysqli_num_rows($post_items) > 0){
        while ($obj = $post_items->fetch_object()) {

            $jsonData[] = $obj;
                    // check if there are any elements in the array
             if(count($imgArray) > 0){
                 // set the img_src index of the jsonData array with the elements of the other array
                $jsonData['img_src'] = $imgArray;
             }
        }




        $i = json_encode($jsonData);

        echo $i;

    }
}
```

Comment: yes you're right. i edited the answer but please note that this will add the same values for `img_src` for every index of `jsonData`